# Why can't Django load static images, but can load image through web url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my Django app, i cannot load images from DB or from local files. But i can load images through image web link.

```
HPGRM\
    hpgrm\
        setting.py and other files
    mahasabha\
        app.py and other files
    static\
        images\
           image1.JPG
    templates\
        base.html
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
```

template:

```
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% static '/orange.jpg' %}" />
    or 
    <img src="{% static 'images/orange.jpg' %}" />


    #This is working perfectly :-
    <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kcj/p5B/Kcjp5Bb6i.png" class="img_size" alt="NewALT" />
```

I tried every possible method available on the internet
moved static directory to every other directory available in project
Changed path in settings.py
Used different images
Loaded images from Db
and more

but still cannot find any answers.
I can, on other hand copy image link from google and use it as src='image.link.from.google' and can successfully load image
    [enter image description here][1]

```
#here is error file
PS E:\Abhi\HPGRM\hpgrm> py manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 27, 2020 - 21:39:23
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'hpgrm.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[27/Apr/2020 21:39:28] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
Not Found: /home/{% static 'mahasabha/images/img.png' }
Not Found: /home/{% static 'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg' }
[27/Apr/2020 21:39:28] "GET /home/%7B%%20static%20'mahasabha/images/img.png'%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2261
[27/Apr/2020 21:39:28] "GET /home/%7B%%20static%20'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg'%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2270
[27/Apr/2020 21:44:17] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
Not Found: /home/{% static 'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg' }
Not Found: /home/{% static 'mahasabha/images/img.png' }
[27/Apr/2020 21:44:17] "GET /home/%7B%%20static%20'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg'%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2270
[27/Apr/2020 21:44:17] "GET /home/%7B%%20static%20'mahasabha/images/img.png'%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2261
[27/Apr/2020 21:44:47] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3208
Not Found: /home/{% static 'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg' }
[27/Apr/2020 21:44:47] "GET /home/%7B%%20static%20'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg'%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2270
[27/Apr/2020 21:59:01] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3287
Not Found: /home/{% static 'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg' }
[27/Apr/2020 21:59:02] "GET /home/%7B%%20static%20'mahasabha/images/orange.jpg'%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2270



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeVVZ.png
```

```
#Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

setting.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mahasabha.apps.MahasabhaConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR, 'mahasabha/static')),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
```

Comment: Please share your actual template file name and settings.py part related to the template engine. And the view code.

Comment: To serve static files locally, you have to append it to your urlpath. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) might solve your problem.

Comment: Already added to urls.py again same result. Maybe python cannot compile .jpg .png for some reasons and is unable to convert to html component

Comment: I have added more code.